# Why changing the id of an article HTML element breaks CSS style?

Tags: html, css

I downloaded a [HTML template](http://html5up.net/astral), started modifying some items and first thing I want to do is to change the `id` attribute for an `<article>` element.

I **only** changed that, and so the site appeareance changed to not a desired one. Console shows **any CSS issues**.

This is original HTML part of code I'm interested:

```
<!-- Nav -->
    <nav id="nav">
        <a href="#me" class="fa fa-home active"><span>Home</span></a>
        <a href="#work" class="fa fa-folder"><span></span></a>
        <a href="#email" class="fa fa-envelope"><span>Email Me</span></a>
        <a href="http://twitter.com/daguilaraguilar" class="fa fa-twitter"><span>Twitter</span></a>
    </nav>

<!-- Main -->
    <div id="main">

        <!-- Me -->
            <article id="me" class="panel">
                <header>
                    <h1>Diego Benjamín <br><br> Aguilar Aguilar</h1>
                    <!-- <span class="byline">Senior Astral Projectionist</span> !-->
```

And just changed:

```
<a href="#start" class="fa fa-home active"><span>Home</span></a>
<article id="start" class="panel">
```

This are the visual changes:

[image]
[image]

What's that I'm missing or should fix?

> **EDIT**

Right after comments I went and saw CSS file and found out:

```
/*********************************************************************************/
/* Panels                                                                        */
/*********************************************************************************/

    #main
    {
        position: relative;
        overflow: hidden;
    }

    .panel
    {
        position: relative;
    }

    /* Me */

        #me
        {
        }

            #me .pic
            {
                position: relative;
                display: block;
            }
```

Comment: Can we see your CSS please?

Comment: The id "me" might have been used in CSS and hence you are getting the unexpected result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because the id `me` is being styled in the `CSS`.

Taken from the CSS (I downloaded it):

```
#me
{
}

#me .pic
{
   position: relative;
   display: block;
}

#me .pic:before
{
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background: url('images/overlay.png');
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

Basically, if you want to change the `#me` ID, you have to go into the `CSS` style sheets and change it there too.

**Update**

There are various different stylesheets. I took that snippet from `style.css`, however there is also `style-desktop.css` that has various different `#me` styled in. My recommendation is to go through every `css` file and edit every instance of `#me` to be what you want.

Answer (score 2):

Like commented by Hamed Ali Khan, the id is probably used in the stylesheet.

In your stylesheet you should change all styles that contain `#me` to `#start`.

Or you could add an extra class to the element. For example `<article id="start" class="extraStyle panel">`. Then you should change all `#me` to `.extraStyle`.

Answer (score 2):

You have to change that thing in CSS file too.

The styles applied with `id` in the CSS, like `#article-id .child{some :style; }`

What you changed in the HTML may reflect the same in CSS too.

Answer (score 2):

This is probably happening because some elements in your CSS are targetted as shown below

```
#foo .bar{
}
```

This means that it affects elements with the class **bar** inside of the element with ID **foo**. That's why changing of an element's ID can really mess up it's content's style.

Answer (score 2):

Replacing the ID broke the styles related to your #home element.

Open your CSS file, and rename all `#home` in `#me`.